# HTML 5 datetime-local controls time mismatch

Tags: html, datetime, breeze

I am using HTML5 datetime-lcoal control in one of my views. The value is correctly saved in the database but breeze is returning a different time value than what is saved.

One of the entries in database is

```
2013-09-20 14:00:00.000
```

The entry was inserted today at 2.00 PM (Eastern Time Zone)

While fetching the value retrieved is

```
Fri Sep 20 2013 10:00:00 GMT-0400
```

Not sure why is this happening. Is it because the datetime-local does not take into consideration the time zone ?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17657459/breezejs-date-is-not-set-to-the-right-time helped me to get the solution.

Comment: I'd love to help, but you didn't show any code.  It's probably because the value is being interpreted as UTC.

Answer (score 0):

Breeze does not manipulate the datetimes going to and from the server in any way EXCEPT to add a UTZ timezone specifier to any dates returned from the server that do not already have one. This is only done because different browsers interpret dates without a timezone specifier differently and we want consistency between browsers.

This is discussed in more detail in the answer [posted here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17657459/breezejs-date-is-not-set-to-the-right-time).