# DateTime from WebApi to Breeze is transformed with the Time Localization

Tags: breeze, asp.net-web-api

I have a form on which I set a start Date and a finish Date for a entity.

On the Web Api side, before saving the date to the database,I set the start date: `2013-09-25 00:00:00.000` and the  the end date as `2013-09-26 23:59:59.000`.

```cs
var vote = (VotingSet)Entity;
vote.Start = new DateTime(vote.Start.Year, vote.Start.Month, vote.Start.Day, 0, 0, 0, 0);
vote.End = new DateTime(vote.End.Year, vote.End.Month, vote.End.Day, 23, 59, 58);
```

This is from the JSON that is send to the rest service looks like this:

- Start: `"2013-09-25T00:00:00.000Z"`
- End: `"2013-09-26T00:00:00.000Z"`

After the save, in the javascript client, the entity is updated with the new key and with the properties that come from the server.

The observable date objects will have the following value

- Start: Wed Sep 25 2013 03:00:00 GMT+0300 (GTB Daylight Time)
- End:   Fri Sep 27 2013 02:59:58 GMT+0300 (GTB Daylight Time)

This is what i am getting back from the server

- Start: `"2013-09-25T00:00:00.000"`
- End: `"2013-09-26T23:59:58.000"`

How can i make sure that the hours in my object are not modified?

EDIT:

There is a a good explaniation [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17657459/breezejs-date-is-not-set-to-the-right-time) on what's happening with the datetime in javascript.

In the end i used this snipped to solve my problem:
            breeze.DataType.parseDateFromServer = function (source) {
                var date = moment(source);
                return date.toDate();
            };
It override's breeze own function with adds a time offset to the datetime.

Comment: Please show some code so we can understand what you are describing.  Also, check those values, they don't look completely valid. Some digits are missing, and the format is nonstandard.  Also, there is no such thing as "local gmt".

Comment: I added the .net code and better examples. Sorry about the first post, really sloby from my part

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Breeze does not manipulate the datetimes going to and from the server in any way EXCEPT to add a UTZ timezone specifier to any dates returned from the server that do not already have one. This is only done because different browsers interpret dates without a timezone specifier differently and we want consistency between browsers.

This is discussed in more detail in the answer [posted here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17657459/breezejs-date-is-not-set-to-the-right-time).

Answer (score 0):

You are passing ISO8601 formatted timestamps, which is good.  When you pass the `Z` at the end, you are indicating that the timestamp represents UTC.  When you load those into JavaScript, it's going to take that into account.

You still need to show more code if you are looking for a useful response.  What you've currently described from .NET doesn't quite line up with the timestamps you've provided.  And it seems like most of this problem has to do with JavaScript and you haven't yet shown any of that code, so I can only guess what you might be doing.  Please update your question, and understand that we have no knowledge of your system other than what you show us.

It's possible you may find [moment.js](http://momentjs.com) to be useful in this scenario, but I can't elaborate further without seeing the relevent JavaScript code.

Comment: Hi, i didn't add any javascript, because i am using breeze.js. When saving and sending data to the server, breeze is taking care of the plumbing and also of the date conversion. hence the tag for breeze