# handling of datetime objects by breeze

Tags: json.net, breeze

We use breeze with API controller.

I want display what dates we have in database to the end user without converting them into UTC.

Same in case if uses chooses any date in the UI it should be saved as it was selected.

I know that JSON.NET date serialization sucks. Also on DOM elements are bound to model properties and it is quite big job to convert date fields into string.

Can you please advise for a fix solution?

I did try implementing custom DateTimeConverterBase and hook it through GLOBAL.ASCX however for some reason my overwritten method does not invoke!

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Show code which demonstrates the problem.  Also, your assertion that "JSON.Net date serialization sucks" does not help your question; it just makes people less likely to want to answer.  If you're having trouble with it, give us details about what isn't working.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simplest way to do this might be to replace Breeze's *breeze.DataType.parseDateFromServer* method.

See the answer to this post for more information: [breezejs-date-is-not-set-to-the-right-time](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17657459/breezejs-date-is-not-set-to-the-right-time)

Comment: Thanks Jay! I did couple quick test and using breeze.DataType.parseDateFromServer seems like fixed my issue. I will keep this post updated in case if I see any further issues.

Comment: Please mark this as answered if this was the issue. thx.