# Dealing with date only datatypes

Tags: date, datetime, breeze

I am using latest breeze.js and I have a question about date only DateTime data types. I have an entity document which have IssueDate and IssuePlace fields. Where IssueDate is date only field (mapped to MsSql as Date column) and IssuePlace is city. For example, document was issued on 01-11-2013 in London. And this info is printed on document. Following this logic I would like to show user in UI (in some kind of input box) this exact date independent of local timezone of users browser. Of course using latest breeze.js.

Generally all my DateTime fields are saved in database as UTC and all operations on those fields are UTC considered (on server and client side). This way all events like when document (date, hours and minutes) have been sent are displayed in local browser timezone what is correct. But what to do with "absolute" date only fields?

Any ideas how to do this using breeze.js?

By the way I noticed commented function *parseDateAsLocal* in breeze.js which do exactly what I need but only the question is how to mark which filed need to be "treated" with this function.

Answer (score 0):

If the column is of type date then there is no associated time to display. The data is simply not saved in the database. I would consider changing the data type to datetimeoffset.

http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb630289.aspx

Comment: If a problem would be passing timezone to browser then you would be correct. However, the "problem" is in behavior of breeze.js and the way javascript Date types works. Like it's written here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17657459/breezejs-date-is-not-set-to-the-right-time