# datetime utc handling with DateTimeZoneHandling

Tags: breeze

i am trying to figure out why my dates on the client are different than my dates on the server...  down below i have a breezeconfig class that i thought would allow my server side "unspecified" dates to be serialized as "utc"... however a date of "2011-08-11" is still being serialized as "2011-08-11T00:00:00.000" which i believe is missing the "Z" at the end in order to signify utc... any ideas? thank you

```
public class BreezeConfig : Breeze.WebApi.BreezeConfig
   {
    protected override Newtonsoft.Json.JsonSerializerSettings CreateJsonSerializerSettings()
    {
        var ret = base.CreateJsonSerializerSettings();
        ret.DateTimeZoneHandling = Newtonsoft.Json.DateTimeZoneHandling.Utc;            
        return ret;
    }        
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Setting `ret.DateTimeZoneHandling = Newtonsoft.Json.DateTimeZoneHandling.Utc;` doesn't work as expected because ret created by the base Breeze.WebApi.BreezeConfig.CreateJsonSerializerSettings() adds [IsoDateTimeConverter](http://james.newtonking.com/json/help/index.html?topic=html/T_Newtonsoft_Json_Converters_IsoDateTimeConverter.htm) to the ret.Converters list. By default IsoDateTimeConverter will not add 'Z' to the output string if DateTime.Kind is DateTimeKind.Unspecified. Like Jay Trabant answered - 
breeze.js fixes this client-side.

With this knowledge it's ease to make your server return all dates as UTC:

```
var isoDateTimeConverter = ret.Converters.OfType<Newtonsoft.Json.Converters.IsoDateTimeConverter>().Single();
isoDateTimeConverter.DateTimeStyles = System.Globalization.DateTimeStyles.AssumeUniversal;
```

Because there is a bug in IsoDateTimeConverter - [Issue with DateTimeStyles](http://json.codeplex.com/workitem/23431), it's better to completely remove IsoDateTimeConverter from the Converters collection and set DateTimeZoneHandling to Utc:

```
public class CustomBreezeConfig : Breeze.ContextProvider.BreezeConfig
{
    protected override Newtonsoft.Json.JsonSerializerSettings CreateJsonSerializerSettings()
    {
        var settings = base.CreateJsonSerializerSettings();
        settings.DateTimeZoneHandling = Newtonsoft.Json.DateTimeZoneHandling.Utc;

        var isoDateTimeConverter = settings.Converters.OfType<Newtonsoft.Json.Converters.IsoDateTimeConverter>().Single();
        settings.Converters.Remove(isoDateTimeConverter);

        return settings;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

My guess is that your server datatype is a DateTime ( not a DateTime2 or DateTimeOffset), and as such has no explicit timezone information.

Breeze does not manipulate the datetimes going to and from the server in any way EXCEPT to add a UTZ timezone specifier to any dates returned from the server *that do not already have one*. This is only done because different browsers interpret dates without a timezone specifier differently and we want consistency between browsers.

This is discussed in more detail in the answer posted here. [breezejs: date is not set to the right time](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17657459/breezejs-date-is-not-set-to-the-right-time)