# How to include time zone in Web API 2 JSON dates?

Tags: json, breeze, asp.net-web-api

How do I **configure** the JSON dates produced by my Web API 2 Controller to include the time zone?
Data type used for dates in SQL Server are datetime and I don’t have the option of changing the Legacy database.

Comment: Only using breeze on the client not the server

Answer (score 1):

Breeze uses Json.NET to serialize/deserialize json.  You can configure the serializer settings that Breeze uses by creating a custom class that inherits from Breeze.ContextProvider.BreezeConfig. Breeze will automatically discover this class and create an instance of it for all configuration tasks.

Something like this:

```
public class CustomBreezeConfig : Breeze.ContextProvider.BreezeConfig
   {
    protected override Newtonsoft.Json.JsonSerializerSettings CreateJsonSerializerSettings()
    {
        var ret = base.CreateJsonSerializerSettings();
        ret.DateTimeZoneHandling = Newtonsoft.Json.DateTimeZoneHandling.Utc; 
        //  ret.DateTimeZoneHandling = Newtonsoft.Json.DateTimeZoneHandling.Local; 
        return ret;
    }        
}
```

But before you go down this path please read this (the response specifically):

[breezejs: date is not set to the right time](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17657459/breezejs-date-is-not-set-to-the-right-time)

Answer (score 0):

Try returning your `DateTime` formatted with `.ToString()` and use a custom date and time format like `"K"`. See: [http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8kb3ddd4(v=vs.110).aspx#KSpecifier](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8kb3ddd4%28v=vs.110%29.aspx#KSpecifier) for more information.