# override breeze.DataType.parseDateFromServer

Tags: breeze

I am trying to override the breeze method as described here [breezejs: date is not set to the right time](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17657459/breezejs-date-is-not-set-to-the-right-time) but it seems it doesn't affect it at all. Do you have any idea ?

Comment: Need a bit more detail. I do know that replacing the 'parseDateFromServer' method with your own implementation does work. And just to be clear the method needs to take an 'arbitrary' source and return a javascript date. What does your 'override' look like? and have you debugged into it?

Comment: I have a singleton module in DURANDAL wherein i have en EntityManager used by all the application for making projection queries. At the top of module i make the override using moment suggested into your post. `breeze.DataType.parseDateFromServer = function (source) {
     var date = moment(source); 
     return date.toDate();   
};` but it seems it's never called during projections

Comment: What is not clear to me is: Do i have to call it manually after the projection ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The *breeze.DataType.parseDateFromServer* method ( or its overridden implementation) will get called anytime breeze determines that the incoming data represents a date.  The way breeze determines this is by using its metadata.

This metadata is available for every *EntityType* but is generally **not** available for per field projections.  In other words, if you perform this query

```
var query = EntityQuery.from("Employees")
     .where('birthDate', '>', new Date(1998, 3, 1));
```

Breeze will bring down a collection of 'Employee' entities where the 'birthDate' property will have gone thru the *parseDateFromServer* method. This is because breeze has metadata about the 'Employee' *EntityType* and knows that the 'birthDate' property represents a date.

The some logic applies to any query involving 'expand' or the 'select' of any properties that return entities. i.e. *parseDateFromServer* is called here as well:

```
var query = EntityQuery.from("Orders").expand("Employee");
```

as well as here:

```
// assuming orderedByEmployee is a property on Order that returns an Employee entity.
var query = EntityQuery.from("Orders").select("orderId, orderedByEmployee");
```

**However**, if you project 'loose' properties then breeze has no idea about their types.  So the following query:

```
var query = EntityQuery.from("Employees")
     .select('employeeId, birthDate");
```

will NOT pass the 'birthDate' property thru *parseDateFromServer*, and will instead return a collection of 'anonymous' json objects each with a numeric 'employeeId' property and a **string** 'birthDate' property.

This reason for this is intrinsic to javascript in that a json serialized date looks exactly like a string, and there is no way to tell from the data itself whether something that looks like a string (formatted with quotes) is actually a string or whether it really represents an underlying date:

In theory, breeze could try to infer the dataType by looking more closely at the data but we decided early on that we shouldn't try to 'guess' at something like this.  We could also have tried to determine that dataType by parsing and evaluating the projection expression but this added a degree of complexity we didn't feel was warranted.

There is a workaround though.  You can tell breeze about the structure of the data that is being returned.  You do this by creating a 'projection' entityType and then telling breeze that this is what you are projecting into via use of the EntityQuery *toType* method.  Something like this:

```
var query = EntityQuery.from("Employees")
     .select('employeeId, birthDate")
     .toType("EmployeeProjection");
```

where the "EmployeeProjection" type is defined like this:

```
var et = new breeze.EntityType({
  shortName: "EmployeeProjection",
  namespace: "MyNamespace"
});
et.addProperty(new breeze.DataProperty({
  name: "employeeId",
  dataType: breeze.DataType.Int32,
}));
et.addProperty(new breeze.DataProperty({
  name: "birthDate",
  dataType: breeze.DataType.DateTime
}));
myEntityManager.metadataStore.addEntityType(et);
```

In this case, the 'birthDate' property in the projected results will go thru *parseDateFromServer*.

Alternatively, you could just call 'parseDateFromServer' yourself manually on those properties that you 'know' are dates.

Hope this makes sense.

Comment: Yes, it absolutely makes sense!i turned out to call the method manually.what sounds strange to me is that tried the overridden method with a  NON PROJECTION query but the result didn't change. i'll make another test and let you know. thx.