# Stop breeze from adding timezone

Tags: breeze

I don't want breeze to tack on the time zone information on the server, or the client. How do I turn this off?

I have a SQL DATE field in the database- I don't want time.  When working with DateTime variables in C#, I always want them set to midnight. I am overriding breeze.DataType.parseDateFromServer on the client as described here https://stackoverflow.com/a/17669486/210757[1](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17669486/210757) but I seem to be still getting the adjustment on the server.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The key point here is that breeze is NOT tacking on time and timezone information. The issue is that dates automatically serialize with a time component because in javascript all dates have a time component. So even if this information is all set to all zeros, it will still be interpreted on the client as a date with a time component.

The second issue is that virtually every browser formats dates according to the browser's own timezone settings.

So the problem is either that the timezone of the server is different from that of the client or the server date is being serialized with no timezone information ( which will be interpreted by breeze as being a UTC date with a zero offset. i.e. which is very unlikely to match your local timezone.) This happens in .NET with server dates declared as DateTime as opposed to DateTime2 or DateTimeOffset.

To fix either of these you will need to replace Breeze's DataType.parseDateFromServer so that you completely ignore the timezone information coming in.

Something like:

```
breeze.DataType.parseDateFromServer = function (source) {
    source = stripTime(source); // you will need to write the stripTime method.
    return new Date(Date.parse(source));
};
```

If you use Moment.js, i think that you can do the following

```
breeze.DataType.parseDateFromServer = function (source) {
   var date = moment(source); 
   return date.toDate();   
};
```