# Breeze DataType.parseDateFromServer in the TypeScript project

Tags: breeze

I am using TempHire Angular 2 as the reference architecture in my current project. I am facing very same issue as in the following Stackoverflow thread i.e unable to save date value in SQL server as input by the user due to UTC issue.

[breezejs: date is not set to the right time](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17657459/breezejs-date-is-not-set-to-the-right-time)

In my Angular2/Typescript project, where I can do the changes as described in the above URL. Typescript syntax is appreciated.

Note: I have already included momentJs in my project.

Answer (score 0):

Please refer.
https://github.com/Breeze/temphire.angular/issues/12

if anyone has similar requirements, I have done the below.

Inside prepare()
{
.........
.........
DataType.parseDateFromServer = this.parseDateAsMoment;
.........
.........
}

parseDateAsMoment(source: any): Date{

```
var date = moment.utc(source, 'YYYY-MM-DD HH-mm-ss');        
return date.toDate();
```

}

In Angular component, ondatechanged event of MyDatePicker.

onDateFromChanged(event: IMyDateModel) {

```
if (event.formatted !== '') {


    var newDate = moment.utc(new Date(event.jsdate).toLocaleDateString()).format('YYYY-MM-DD HH-mm-ss')
    var newDate2 = moment.utc(newDate, 'YYYY-MM-DD HH-mm-ss');
    this.model.dateFrom = newDate2.toDate();
}
```

}

Only then the date input stores correctly in SQL Server datetime column.