# UTC/Timezones in Breeze

Tags: breeze, utc

I am working with Breeze and running into some date/time issues.

I have a field in a form, with a date time picker, that is returning a value of 07/20/2018 14:00. For this example, assume I am in CST timezone (GMT -0500). What I would like to do is pass that value to my Breeze entity manager and have it saved in my database correctly. I get the date into a variable:

```
dateVariable = ctx.ChosenTime;
```

This works and puts a value of 07/20/2018 14:00 into the variable dateVariable.

I create a new entity:

```
var newEntity = entityManager.createEntity('Test Entity', {Date: dateVariable};
```

And when I debug and check the value of newEntity, it has a property called Date with the proper value. However, once I call entityManager.SaveChanges(), and then get the returned value back, it is displayed as 07/20/2018 19:00. Since Breeze is handling the display value (via data binding), I am not sure why this is happening. Any advice would be appreciated. Thanks

Comment: What value is saved on the server?  If you look at the Network tab of your browser's F12 dev tools, what value is sent by `SaveChanges()`, and what value is sent back from the server?

Comment: "2018-07-20T16:00:00.000Z" is what is sent when I choose 1100 (or 11:00am) on a server that is located in CST, so that seems right. When I get it back, it is sent as  "2018-07-20T16:00:00.000". The response doesn't have that Z at the end, so it gets interpretted as local time?

Comment: Here is the odd part, when I execute a query in breeze to pull it back out, the raw data I get back is 10 hours off ("Fri, 20 Jul 2018 21:00:00 GMT")

Answer (score 0):

When the JSON response comes from the server, if the date string does not have a timezone specifier, Breeze assumes it is in UTC and puts a "Z" on the end before parsing.  So it converts your local time to UTC after the round-trip to the server.  The solutions are:

1. Change your server-side property to `DateTimeOffset` or similar data type that preserves the timezone of a date.  This way the returned date will have a time zone.
2. Tell Breeze not to add the "Z" and just interpret the date in local time.  See [this SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17669486/2517406) for more information.

Comment: This is a great answer and very useful. It made me think a bit more about how my system should handle timezones. I would want Breeze (and MVC 5) to handle it as follows: if a user in Alaska enters a time of 7:00pm, when a user in NYC loads the same data, they should see 7:00pm.